# How to increase efficiency of the loop

Tags: r, loops

I have a data set like this:

```
set.seed(1000)
df <- data.frame(exp = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", rep("B", 5)), di = rnorm(10, 20, 3), x = rnorm(10, 5, 0.2), y = rnorm(10, 5, 0.2))
```

in fact it is huge (> 10000 rows) but the designe is similar. I want to calculate the new value for each row in the dataset that is a sum of values in the group that are greater than the value in the row. For small data set such a loop works fine:

```
df$comp1 <- 0
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
      for (j in 1:nrow(df)){
          dist = sqrt((df$x[j] - df$x[i])^2 + (df$y[j] - df$y[i])^2)
        if (dist < 0.4 & df$exp[i] == df$exp[j] & df$di[j] > df$di[i]){
          df$comp1[i] = df$comp1[i] + df$di[j]
        }
      }

    }
```

Results should be like this

```
   exp       di        x        y    comp1
1    A 18.66267 4.803514 5.534014  0.00000
2    A 16.38243 4.889102 4.754597 39.55850
3    A 20.12338 5.024276 5.166849 21.91817
4    A 21.91817 4.975826 5.106514  0.00000
5    A 17.64034 4.732792 4.870635 21.91817
6    B 18.84353 5.034011 5.120632 22.15925
7    B 18.57240 5.031016 4.643231  0.00000
8    B 22.15925 5.004986 5.066988  0.00000
9    B 19.94448 4.590683 5.112195  0.00000
10   B 15.88065 5.042631 5.244187 41.00278
```

However, it takes ages when I run it on the whole dataset. Any ideas how to speed it up. 
BR

Comment: Could you describe what you're trying to achieve exactly in words ? So we don't have to guess from your actual code.

Comment: Try to avoid `for` loops with R. Vectorised functions or, failing that, the `apply()` family are usually the way to go.

Comment: @Phil do you mean that it is possible to write such function as the `apply()` FUN argument?

Comment: @Mateusz1981 How do you get round numbers ...

Comment: they are round as di is a `int`

Comment: You forgot it in your code...

Comment: they are + `+ df$di[j]` in the last row

Comment: And ? how does adding an integer with a float doesn't give a float ? (rnorm return a float)

Comment: but float is a `dist`and `di`is integer. I want to add just integers (di)

Comment: I mean your initial df has only float numbers....

Comment: I updated my answer to get the proper results and added a benchmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option with library `data.table` if I properly get your requirements:

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)
 df[,comp:={ lv=(df$exp == exp); dx=x-df$x[lv] ;dy=y-df$y[lv]; lv2=((dx^2+dy^2) < 0.4^2 & di<df$di[lv]); sum(df$di[lv2 & lv])}, by=1:nrow(df)]
```

Results:

```
    exp       di        x        y     comp
 1:   A 18.66267 4.803514 5.534014  0.00000
 2:   A 16.38243 4.889102 4.754597 39.55850
 3:   A 20.12338 5.024276 5.166849 21.91817
 4:   A 21.91817 4.975826 5.106514  0.00000
 5:   A 17.64034 4.732792 4.870635 21.91817
 6:   B 18.84353 5.034011 5.120632 22.15925
 7:   B 18.57240 5.031016 4.643231  0.00000
 8:   B 22.15925 5.004986 5.066988  0.00000
 9:   B 19.94448 4.590683 5.112195  0.00000
10:   B 15.88065 5.042631 5.244187 41.00278
```

with some details of what is done inside the `j` part of the data.table call:

```
lv=(df$exp == exp); # Get  a logical vector of the initial df to subset
dx=x-df$x[lv] # Do the differences between actual row x and all others by exp
dy=y-df$y[lv] # same for y
lv2=((dx^2+dy^2) < 0.4^2 & di<df$di[lv]) # make a logical vector where the distance is within a 0.4 radius, and the values above current value.
sum(df$di[lv2 & lv])]) # sum the di which match the union of 'exp' value with radius and absolute value computed above.
```

The syntax `comp:={}` allow us to create a new column filled witht he result of our inner function.

Benchmark on this small dataset:

Code used:

```
set.seed(1000)
entry <- data.frame(exp = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", rep("B", 5)), di = rnorm(10, 20, 3), x = rnorm(10, 5, 0.2), y = rnorm(10, 5, 0.2))

f.dt <-function(df) {
  setDT(df)
  df[,comp1:={lv=(df$exp == exp); dx=x-df$x[lv];dy=y-df$y[lv];lv2=((dx^2+dy^2)<0.4^2 & di<df$di[lv]);sum(df$di[lv2 & lv])},by=1:nrow(df)][]
}

f.ori <-function(df) {
  df$comp1 <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    for (j in 1:nrow(df)){
      dist = sqrt((df$x[j] - df$x[i])^2 + (df$y[j] - df$y[i])^2)
      if (dist < 0.4 & df$exp[i] == df$exp[j] & df$di[j] > df$di[i]){
        df$comp1[i] = df$comp1[i] + df$di[j]
      }
    }
  }
  df
}
```

Check and benchmark:

```
> identical(f.ori(entry),f.dt(entry))
[1] TRUE
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(f.ori(entry),f.dt(entry),times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
         expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 f.ori(entry) 16.597134 16.790708 24.687390 17.854078 18.036534 69.344878    10   b
  f.dt(entry)  2.812088  3.013074  3.127194  3.126967  3.209214  3.492588    10  a
```

So it's around 6 times quicker on this small dataset, on a larger one I think the increase of speed will be exponential.

Comment: These results don't seem to match the OP's expected results?

Comment: @Phill see last line of my answer, I did base my code on the description more than the code. I do think the comparison in the OP loop is wrong. I'll  correct it if this is not the case

Comment: @Phill just got why I'm wrong. I'll tackle it back after lunch

Comment: you were right @Tensibai. I had `options` on that prevented `float`